# If in a category $\mathcal{C}$ we have that $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set, is then $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ a set?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

in the definition of a small category $\mathcal{C}$ we have that both $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and  $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ have to be sets, so my question is if $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set, isn't $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ also a set?

I've tried to prove it in ZFC axiomatic but I'm not able to do it.

I think what we essentially need to proof is that
$$A=\left\{ \mathcal{C}(X,Y): X,Y \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C}) \right\}$$
is a set, beacuse then we just have that $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})=\bigcup A$.

So, can someone proof that fact? And if it is not true, can someone give and example of a category where $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set, but  $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ is not?

Comment: It depends on your definition of category: do you require it to be *locally small*, i.e. that the $C(X,Y)$ themselves be sets ?

Answer (score 5):

Recall that we call a category $\mathcal{C}$ *locally small* if for any two objects $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ we have that $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y)$ is a set. If $\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set then $\operatorname{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set if and only if $\mathcal{C}$ is locally small.

From left to to right is immediate: since $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y) \subseteq \operatorname{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ for any $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ we have that $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y)$ must be a set. The converse is like your idea. We have that $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y)$ is a set for all objects $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$. Since $\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set, we have that $\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \times \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set. So
$$
\{\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y) : (X, Y) \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \times \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \}
$$
is a set, and so is its union, which is exactly $\operatorname{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$.

If we do not require $\mathcal{C}$ to be locally small then it is not hard to come up with a counterexample. We can define a category $\mathcal{C}$ as follows: it has only one object, say $\star$. We define the arrows of $\mathcal{C}$ to be the class of all sets, so this is a proper class. They all have domain and codomain $\star$, since that is the only object. Composing arrows $A$ and $B$ is done by taking their union. It is easy to check that this is associative and the empty set forms the identity arrow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in the course I'm taking we refer to locally small categories as simply categories so my exact question is why if $\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set and every $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y)$ is also a set then $$\{\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y) : (X, Y) \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \times \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \}$$ is a set? I mean, how do we know is not a proper class?

Comment: @Eparoh It is standard to only consider locally small categories. Most categories of interest are locally small anyway. The reason that that is a set is because each $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y)$ is a set and we only consider set-many of them (because $\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \times \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ is a set). If you want to be really formal (in ZFC) you could use the axiom schema of replacement. The $\operatorname{Hom}(-, -)$ operation is functional on $\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \times \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})$ (by local smallness), so its image is a set.

Comment: I had thought all of that, my problem is that a function is a set of ordered pairs (that satisfies certain conditions), so to establish that $\operatorname{Hom}(-, -)$ is a function, I need some set $A$ to say that $\operatorname{Hom}(-, -) \subset (\operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C}) \times \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{C})) \times A$

Comment: @Eparoh - For the purposes of applying Replacement you do not need to show that you have such a set. The point of replacement is to *give you* that set, provided you have an appropriately formed definition of the function.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Every monoid $M$ can be regarded as a category with a single element $\star$ and morphisms $\{f_m\colon\star\to\star\mid m\in M\}$ whose compositions beheave as in the monoid $M$, namely $f_{m_1}\circ f_{m_2}=f_{m_1m_2}$, so in order to find a category with set many objects and class many morphisms we only need a class sized monoid. Natural examples of such objects are cardinal/ordinals under addition.